# How to solve iOS deployment target issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, deployment

I am trying to run an application I am developing on an iPhone that runs iOS 10.2.1. I also tried to run it on a simulator that runs iOS 10.2. My Xcode version is 8.3.3. Even though I changed the deployment target to 8.0, I get the following error when I try to run it on a device under 10.3. Are there other things I should pay attention when changing the deployment target other than changing it from Info tab in Xcode? The error states the deployment target as 10.3 but it is not. How can I get around this issue?

["Run destination is not valid for running the scheme.."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC9WV.png)

[My deployment target](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tb9kp.png)

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember the same issue happening in my code.

In my case,  I realized that I had not updated my `Base SDK` to the latest iOS version in the `Build Settings`

To do so, click on `Project name -> Build Settings -> Base SDK`

[image]

If Base SDK does not show, ensure that "All" is selected in the filter at the top of the page.

Also, sometimes the project has multiple targets and you might be setting the Base SDK on the wrong target.

Comment: My Base SDK seems to be the latest iOS version. How can I check if the project has multiple targets and also how can I know whether I am setting the Base SDK on the wrong target? Can I check Base SDK's of separate targets?

Comment: You can see list of all the Targets under the Target Tab as shown in attached screenshot (Targets hidden in screenshot). Click on each target and verify base SDK. Worth a shot.

Comment: iOS deployment target was different for different targets. I changed it under Target Tab and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The issue still occurs in Xcode 12 (wtf Apple). You can fix it by changing target value under Target -> Build Settings -> iOS Deployment Target.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your iphone to the newer version or downgrade your xcode version.  Currently they are out of sync thus why you are seeing this error.

See here for compatibility: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: He's describing a situation when iOS on his device is same or lower than deployment target in Xcode.